# How many unique paths are there from point $A$ to $A$ and from $B$ to $B$?

Tags: combinatorics

This is part of the exam of one university.

The task is to calculate number of unique paths from $A$ to $A$ so that all lines are crossed and all lines are crossed only once.

Second task is same, just for the point of $B$.

I managed to calculate it manually by checking all the paths - for $A$ it's 24 and for $B$ it's 12.

But is there a faster intuitive way to calculate number of paths?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $4$ paths joining A and C and you can traverse them in any order, so for part a) the answer is $4!$.  There are only $2$ paths leading to B, so you will have to leave B on one of them and come back on the other ($2$ choices.)  In between, you can traverse the $3$ paths between A and C that don't pass through B in any order.  This gives $2\cdot3!=12.$

Comment: Nice, thank you!